# Has anyone implemented the leaflet.shapefile plugin?

Tags: shapefile, javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to implement the leaflet.shapefile plugin to enable a user to upload a zipped shapefile and overlay it on my webmapping site as can be done in the demo version of the site. http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/

When the page I've created loads before I even click the button to upload a file I get an error which is from the the setWorkerEvents() function (line124) in the script.js file. When I click to upload a file it goes through the steps but seems to stop when the worker.data function is called from Line 76 of the code script.js.

I created a gist https://gist.github.com/dodriscoll/4a96f825ebe8123070b4 with 3 of the files being used, I think the issue is with the script.js file.

Comment: Take a look at [calvinmetcalf's github for leaflet.shapefile](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile)

Comment: Are you testing with an up to date browser without extensions?

Comment: u can covert the shapefile.zip to geojson then http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson